# define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

we are getting ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources in when executing a job in Jenkins

Installed SonarQube Scanner plugin version 2.8.1

```
In Jenkins job configuration Build section,Added Execute SonarQube Scnanner with analysis properties
-Dsonar.projectKey 
-Dsonar.projectName
-Dsonar.projectVersion
-Dsonar.sourceEncoding
-Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath
-Dsonar.analysis.mode
-Dsonar.github.repository
-Dsonar.host.url
-Dsonar.login
-Dsonar.password
-Dsonar.github.oauth
-Dsonar.github.pullRequest
-Dsonar.github.disableInlineComments
-Dsonar.github.endpoint
```

This is a java project. 
we tried the same with sonarQube scanner version 2.1, it is working fine.
We are facing issue with sonarQube Scanner version 2.8.1, how to resolve this issue.

Comment: What's the question in here?

Comment: @Peska: updated the question.

Comment: I see a lot all properties, but all of them are empty. It is hard to say what is wrong when you didn't show the configuration, inform about used build tools etc ;)